# Create a MySQL Database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

`let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  password: '1234',
  database: 'data101', 
  port: 3306
});`

I'm trying to create a Database using MySQL package for NodeJS, should I create the database name previously manually? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: not necessarily, and yes

Answer (score 0):

Your code allows to connect to Mysql. In order to create a mysql database, you need to write your code like this.

```
CREATE DATABASE playlistDB; //this line creates the database

USE playlistDB;

CREATE TABLE songs(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  artist VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  genre VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

In order to connect to the database, your code should look like the following lines.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3306,

  // Your username
  user: "root",

  // Your password
  password: "",
  database: "playlistDB"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("connected as id " + connection.threadId);
});
```

Comment: The point is on connection: database name wanna be created dynamically